# Sort Timestamp into half hour blocks

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, datetime, timestamp

So I have a bunch of Timestamps that I want to sort into half hour blocks so I can display them in a table that shows all the objects in their respective 30 minute window.

I was thinking about looping through them and converting each into a string and them comparing the 2 Hour and 2 Minute Digits with a switch statement but this seems very tedious/inefficient and vulnerable to errors.

Any idea of how I should go about this more effectively?

Comment: You shouldn't have to convert the timestamps to `String`; whatever Java class you're using to read these timestamps will have ways to let you access the hour and minute parts directly.

Answer (score 3):

Do an integer division of the epoch time milliseconds by 1800000 (30min in ms). That is now your key; every unit is a distinct 30 minutes since 1970 jan 1st 0h00 utc.

Mysql specifically, has UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timefield) to get it in seconds, so divide by 1800 in your case. This means you can do groupby and where clauses nicely on the server side, if required.

Comment: Or seconds, if that's more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Spelling [user2023577’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071939/5772882) out:

```
    Instant[] instants = {
            Instant.parse("2018-04-28T06:17:00Z"),
            Instant.parse("2018-04-28T07:56:00Z"),
            Instant.parse("2018-04-28T07:33:00Z"),
            Instant.parse("2018-04-28T07:13:00Z"),
            Instant.parse("2018-04-28T06:25:00Z"),
            Instant.parse("2018-04-28T06:13:00Z")
    };

    final long blockSizeSeconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(30);
    Map<Long, List<Instant>> grouped = Arrays.stream(instants)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getEpochSecond() / blockSizeSeconds));
    grouped.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints three groups:

```
[2018-04-28T06:17:00Z, 2018-04-28T06:25:00Z, 2018-04-28T06:13:00Z]
[2018-04-28T07:13:00Z]
[2018-04-28T07:56:00Z, 2018-04-28T07:33:00Z]
```